# unable to initialize datasource using java annotation on bluemix

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a java application running on a bluemix cloud server, I originally developed it locally on a tomcat server and then decided to migrate to the cloud. The option suggested everywhere was to use liberty and sqldb services which after some finicking I got setup on my bluemix account with the sql database named SQL-RCT bound as a service to my java application.

The problem is encountered when running the following code:

```
@WebServlet({ "/LoginServlet", "/" })
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Connection conn;

@Resource(lookup="jdbc/SQL-RCT")
private DataSource myDataSource;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LoginServlet() {
    super();
    try {
        if(myDataSource == null){
            throw new Exception("no data source");
        }
        conn = myDataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when I try to load the servlet I get an error that there was a nullpointer exception in my init function which I quickly was able to narrow down to my myDataSource object being null.

I've checked the server.xml and I´m using the right name for the lookup but the lookup doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated.

the server.xml

```
<server>
<featureManager>
    <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
    <feature>el-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
    <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jsonp-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
    <feature>icap:managementConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appstate-1.0</feature>
    <feature>cloudAutowiring-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
<application name='myapp' location='myapp.war' type='war' context-root='/'/>
<cdi12 enableImplicitBeanArchives='false'/>
<httpEndpoint id='defaultHttpEndpoint' host='*' httpPort='${port}'/>
<webContainer trustHostHeaderPort='true' extractHostHeaderPort='true'/>
<include location='runtime-vars.xml'/>
<logging logDirectory='${application.log.dir}' consoleLogLevel='INFO'/>
<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage='false'/>
<applicationMonitor dropinsEnabled='false' updateTrigger='mbean'/>
<config updateTrigger='mbean'/>
<appstate appName='myapp' markerPath='${home}/../.liberty.state'/>
<dataSource id='db2-SQL-RCT' jdbcDriverRef='db2-driver' jndiName='jdbc/SQL-RCT' statementCacheSize='30' transactional='true'>
    <properties.db2.jcc id='db2-SQL-RCT-props' databaseName='${cloud.services.SQL-RCT.connection.db}' user='${cloud.services.SQL-RCT.connection.username}' password='${cloud.services.SQL-RCT.connection.password}' portNumber='${cloud.services.SQL-RCT.connection.port}' serverName='${cloud.services.SQL-RCT.connection.host}'/>
</dataSource>
<jdbcDriver id='db2-driver' libraryRef='db2-library'/>
<library id='db2-library'>
    <fileset id='db2-fileset' dir='${server.config.dir}/lib' includes='db2jcc4.jar db2jcc_license_cu.jar'/>
</library>
</server>
```

Comment: could you add your `server.xml`? Is it being instantiated? are you using spring?

Comment: no I´m not using spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injected resources are not available within servlet constructors, since the resources do not get injected until after the servlet instance has been fully initialized.

**Instead, override the javax.servlet.GenericServlet init() method and get your conneciton there.**  This lifecycle method will give you similar lifecycle behavior as how you are currently trying to create your connection in the servlet constructor.

Example code:

```
@WebServlet({ "/LoginServlet", "/" })
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Connection conn;

    @Resource(lookup="jdbc/SQL-RCT")
    private DataSource myDataSource;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        try {
            conn = myDataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**As a side note:** 
Since Liberty pools connections, it's not necessary to store a connection at the class scope.  If you get connections when they are needed and close them once you are done using them, you should not see any performance difference.
If you want to get a connection in the servlet init code as a way to eagerly get a connection, that is fine, but it will impact your servlet load time.

Answer (score 0):

In most containers, the naming convention for the `@Resource` annotation is as follows:

```
@Resource(name = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/SQL-RCT")
    private DataSource myDataSource;
```

Found it on this answer:

[JNDI @Resource annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139617/jndi-resource-annotation)

Comment: this doesn´t work, is there a specific naming convention for the bluemix db2?

Comment: Yep, it doesnt work, I checkd out here: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/02/07/java-db2-10-minutes/

Comment: Can you try initializing the context by using : `DataSource ds=(DataSource)InitialContext.doLookup("java:jdbc/SQL-RCT");`? and see if it works or post here any exceptions it occurs here?

Comment: [err] javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:jdbc/SQL-RCT
[err]  at javax.naming.InitialContext.doLookup(Unknown Source)
[err]  at [internal classes]
[err]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
...
[INFO    ] J2CA8050I: An authentication alias should be used instead of defining a user name and password on dataSource[db2-SQL-RCT].
[WARNING ] DSRA8020E: Warning: The property 'id' does not exist on the DataSource class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.

Comment: Ok, I dug through and found this: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/164214/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-database-outside-bluemi.htm%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bl/

Comment: that is not useful, in the link they have a remote database, here I´m using the standard SQLDB service. his solution is the default implementation of the file/folder structure like bluemix will arrange it for you automaticaly.